# How to find exact word from sentence

Tags: vb.net

In my window application i want to find the exact word from a sentence.the two field will be a textbox(word) and richtextbox(sentence) respectively.

I've used Str(i).contains(word) and  For Each match As Match In Regex.Matches(str(i), word).

But these two does not get the exact word.For example ,
Word:ate
sentence:parfaite ment aux exigences cre**ate** évolutives du marché d aujourd hui

in the above it fetches the ate in create.but i need to focus onle ate not with combined.

Comment: Add space before and after your **word**, no ?

Comment: How 'bout use `indexOf`. When it finds the first occurrence, start the search again with start index = first occurrence index plus search string length. Do it until `indexOf` return -1

Comment: thanks Adrien..Adding space will fail to fetch in some case like the word was end of the statement.Can u plz add a sample for the second one?

Comment: Have you looked at doing this with a regular expression?  You could craft one to look for characters on either side of your word which aren't A-Z or 0-9 (or anything else you want, really).

Comment: Thanks Suzi.But we can't change in uppercase

Answer (score 4):

In your Regex.Matches, you need to use \b word boundaries character. I just wrote an example code in C#, and now I noticed that your question is for VB.NET, so I'll add both code examples:

**C#:**

```
        //Example 1:
        var testString = "parfaite ment aux exigences create évolutives du marché d aujourd hui";
        var pattern = "ate";
        MatchCollection found = Regex.Matches(testString, @"\b" + pattern + @"\b");

        if (found.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Match f in found)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at position {1} in given testString.", f.Value, f.Index);
            }
        }
        else Console.WriteLine("No matches in given testString.");


        //Example 2:
        var testString1 = "parfaite ment aux exigences cre*ate* évolutives du marché d aujourd hui I don't know the language but this: ate and the last one should be found: ate!";
        var pattern1 = "ate";
        MatchCollection found1 = Regex.Matches(testString1, @"\b" + pattern1 + @"\b");

        if (found1.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Match f in found1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at position {1} in given testString1.", f.Value, f.Index);
            }
        }
        else Console.WriteLine("No matches in given testString1.");

        Console.ReadLine();
```

**VB.NET:**

```
    'Example 1:
    Dim testString = "parfaite ment aux exigences create évolutives du marché d aujourd hui"
    Dim pattern = "ate"
    Dim found As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(testString, "\b" & pattern & "\b")

    If found.Count > 0 Then
        For Each f In found
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at position {1} in given testString.", f.Value, f.Index)
        Next
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("No matches in given testString.")
    End If

    'Example 2:
    Dim testString1 = "parfaite ment aux exigences cre*ate* évolutives du marché d aujourd hui I don't know the language but this: ate and the last one should be found: ate!"
    Dim pattern1 = "ate"
    Dim found1 As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(testString1, "\b" & pattern1 & "\b")

    If (found1.Count > 0) Then

        For Each f As Match In found1
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at position {1} in given testString1.", f.Value, f.Index)
        Next
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("No matches in given testString1.")
    End If

    Console.ReadLine()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help?

```
Private Sub SearchForWord()
    Dim SearchString() As String = Split("ate parfaite ment aux exigences cre*ate* évolutives du marché d aujourd hui", " ")
    Dim WordToFind As String = "ate"
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim NumMatches As Integer = 0

    Do Until count = UBound(SearchString)
        If UCase$(WordToFind) = UCase$(SearchString(count)) Then
            NumMatches = NumMatches + 1
        End If
        count = count + 1
    Loop

    Debug.Print(Format(NumMatches))

End Sub
```